# Try to add a VirtualHost

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have a web server with a website and i want to add another address for pre-production use.

Here the existant:

httpd.conf:

```
ServerAdmin support@toto.com
ServerName www.toto.com:80
DocumentRoot "/home/tutu/var/www/html"
```

modules/vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@toto.com
    ServerName www.toto.com:80
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog /home/tutu/var/log/httpd/error-mod_log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /home/tutu/var/log/httpd/access-mod_log common-cookie

   <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have tried to add another VirtualHost but the new address not working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@toto.com
    ServerName www2.toto.com:80
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog /home/tutu/var/log/httpd/error-www2_log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /home/tutu/var/log/httpd/access-www2_log common-cookie
    DocumentRoot "/home/tutu/var/www2/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

The address www2.toto.com is not working.
Have you an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added www2.toto.com to DNS?
It's not added to public DNS yet. (But www.toto.com is)

"Not working" is not very specific. Do you get the default Apache web-page for that site or do you not reach the server? If it's the latter, DNS lookup is likely your real problem, not the Apache config.

The Apache-config looks good, but you should not need to specify :80 as the alias port.

Comment: sorry, i don't reach the server.